MIPI D-PHY over long length various cables
We are trying to transmit video signal from MIPI driver/processor board to a display over long distance. The board / display are using MIPI D-PHY. We have used interposers so we could bring in a I-PEX connector and micro coax cable with 36 AWG. Only one of 8 of our cables worked, the rest did not. This signal was not that great looking on the scope as you might imagine, but it did make an image.  We feel the micro coax cable had impedance insertion loss. We are now in the middle of building interposers for both RJ45 and InfiniBand cables, we feel these cables have much larger awg, impedance matching will be good and readily available off the shelf..  The interposers are done for the RJ45 but we are not getting an image. I have seen discussion about up driver but we cannot have additional circuitry away from the driver board due to potential EMI so we really are probably pushing the envelope but really need to know if we can get the signal to go further than intended which is 10 to 12 feet. As mentioned we have gotten it to work on a single 10 foot 36 AWG micro coax cable with I-PEX connectors. Possibly this was a miracle.
Here are my questions:

We have built interposers using RJ45 and we are not getting an image no matter what length the cable is. In theory we should now not have to worry much about impedance and the wires are much bigger. I have seen discussions about tools to measure MIPI signal integrity.  Can someone please tell me if these could help us here? I'm unclear how these tools might work and could they attach to our RJ45 connectors?

We are currently building interposers that will use InfiniBand cables, I am wondering if the testers could work with these cables as well as we may have issues when we go to testing.?

Has anybody else done this using either of the above two cable assemblies? And if so, what was your strategy/ what problems did you run into.



There appears to be some confusion here... Whether impedance control is important (it is). "impedance insertion loss" isn't a thing, it's (probably) two things. RJ45 is a connector standard, not a type of cable. Trying to swap in random cables isn't going to help. etc...

What you're attempting (long distance transmission) isn't compatible with the design goals of MIPI D-PHY, which explicitly limits the signal flight time to 2ns, and capacitive load to ~70pF (about 250-300mm for practical purposes)... You've not specified a distance, but I imagine you'd be much better off using a different technology to bridge that gap.

Thanks for your response I fully realized that the d-py is not meant for our application unfortunately we don't manufacture the driver board or the display.  I'm reading that the a-phy would likely work for us.  What is a bit confusing to us is why we got a good image going more than 10 ft using micro coax and an ipex connector. I feel it's leading my Engineers to think this could be done with a Infinitiband cable.   We have pretty much abandoned the idea of trying the RJ45 but they feel strong that the Infinitiband could work. I do understand this type of cable assembly is high-end.

You seem quite knowledgeable in this area and let me know if we could perhaps have a phone call I would pay you for your time. I'm spending quite a bit of time and resources going down different paths and I would like to make sure I choose the best option.

Hi Attie,
I have not heard back from you so I am checking to see if you received my last chat?

Also, oddly we have been able to get our standard MIPI D-PHY to now provide video over 14 feet of rj45 cat 7 cable.  We are more interested in using InfiniBand cable though.  Either way it would be great to have some experienced support during our project path.

I'm happy to discuss more via email, though this isn't really a recruitment platform(!)
